# How to get the route name when location changes?

Tags: angularjs

I defined some routes:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config('$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/aaa', { templateUrl: '/111.html' })
                  .when('/bbb', { templateUrl: '/222.html'});
  });
```

And I want to get the route name when user changes the route:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(scope, current, pre) {
      // how to get current route name, e.g. /aaa or /bbb
      console.log('Current route name: ' + ???);
    }
  }]);
```

But I don't know how to get it. I can get the `templateUrl`, but not the route name.

---

**UPDATE**

A more complex use case:

```
$routeProvider.when('/users/:id', { templateUrl: '/show_user.html' })
```

If current path is:

```
/users/12345
```

It should match `/users/:id`, but how do I know which route is matched and to get the route name `/users/:id`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can inject the $location service and make use of its path() function.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .run(['$rootScope','$location', '$routeParams', function($rootScope, $location, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, current, pre) {
      console.log('Current route name: ' + $location.path());
      // Get all URL parameter
      console.log($routeParams);
    });
  }]);
```

You can find other useful $location methods in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location)

**UPDATE**

If you want to have an array of your current route parameters, just inject the $routeParams service like I did above.

Comment: FYI: The first argument to an even handler in Angular isn't the scope, it's an event. I've edited your code snippet to reflect this.  FWIW, the `currentScope` is available on the event object.

Comment: it got bad syntax and even after fix doesnt work saying: Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams

Comment: @Mike, that isn't the syntax.  You need to add a dependency on the Route service on your module.  `angular.module('ngApp', [ 'ngRoute', ...])`

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to inject `$location` and `$routeParams`.
You can use `current.$$route.originalPath`

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, pre) {
        console.log(current.$$route.originalPath);
    });
});
```

This is enough for simple routes (without `:id`, etc.).

With the more complex use case, it will return `/users/:id`.
But you can extract the `:id` param from `current.params.id` and replace it in the full route.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, pre) {
        var fullRoute = current.$$route.originalPath,
            routeParams = current.params,
            resolvedRoute;

        console.log(fullRoute);
        console.log(routeParams);

        resolvedRoute = fullRoute.replace(/:id/, routeParams.id);
        console.log(resolvedRoute);
    });
});
```

Depending on exactly what you need do with the route string, this could be messy compared to Flek's answer (e.g. if you have several params), or if you don't want to be bound to the route params names.

**Also Note**: There's a missing closing brace in your code for the `$on` opening brace.

**Edit 15/01/2014**

Looks like the `$$` properties in Angular are suggested to be private and we should not call them directly from our code.

Answer (score 2):

Not a very elegant solution, and I have only tested it in Chrome DevTools, but it seems to work:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf($route.current) === $route.routes['/users/:id];
```

For others wanting to use this, just replace `'/users/:id'` with the pattern that you used when you defined your route.

Also if you want to match the otherwise path, just use `$route.routes['null']`

**Disclaimer**: This is just a workaround that I found and which works for me. Given that this behavior is not documented, and that I didn't test it to see if it works in all scenarios, use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily get the path from `current`

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, pre) {
        console.log(current.originalPath); // Do not use $$route here it is private
    });
});
```