# AngularJS dynamically set param of ngInclude based on route

Tags: javascript, dynamic, angularjs, include

I'm trying to dynamically include a template into my index.html. The general structure of index.html is:

```
<body>

  <header ng-controller="Main">
    <section>
      <!-- global stuff -->
    </section>
    <section ng-include="moduleName + '/views/menubar.html'">
      <!-- module-based stuff -->
    </section>
  </header>

  <div id="view" ng-view></div>

</body>
```

Sample URL

```
example.com/<app_name>/index.html#/<module_name>[/method_name]
```

I can't figure out how to update `$scope.moduleName` when the route changes. My trouble is two-fold:

1. The header's controller is *Main*, not the controller associated with the view, so I can't? update `$scope.moduleName` from the view's controller (because *Main* and the view's controller are siblings).
2. In *Main*, I tried setting a `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',…)`, but apparently [it is not notified of route changes](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/ib2wHQozeNE).

I've thought of setting up a $rootScope.$on listener (as described in [SO#15355346](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15355346/758177)) for the route change and broadcasting down to children, who then emit back up their route, which is broadcasted back down so it is available to *Main*. But that seems heinous.

And I would really prefer to keep the header outside of ng-view.

**EDIT** I noticed that `$route.current.scope` has an object named with `module_name` (possibly because the name of the controller associated with the route's module_name is the same). I'm wondering if I might be able to somehow use the name of that object…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what's wrong in your code without the full picture. Things you show look fine to me.

Please see [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBZ7pYuu2MZq4TVXohMj?p=preview) I've created to display the ability to do it. Take note that you also can extend route objects with custom properties, like `moduleName` here:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/page1', {
        template: 'one',
        controller: 'one',
        moduleName: 'firstModule'
    });
```

Comment: YES! thank you! Good to know I can define custom properties in $routeProvider too.