# Angularjs highlight menu item when address is random

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code:
Html

```
<li ng-class="{ highlight: isActive('/admin/trackDef/list') || isActive('/admin/trackDef/add')}">
    <a href="${createLink(uri: '/#/admin/trackDef/list')}"></a>
</li>
```

Js controller

```
.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
    $scope.isAnyActiveAdmin = function () {
        return ['/admin/trackDef/list', '/admin/trackDef/add', '/admin/country/list','/admin/country/add', '/admin/user/list', '/admin/user'].indexOf($location.path()) > -1;
    };
}])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/admin/trackDef/list', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/trackDef/trackDef-list.tpl.html',
            controller: 'PaginatedListController',
            resolve: {Service: 'TrackDefServices'}
        }).
        when('/admin/trackDef/add', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/trackDef/trackDef-save.tpl.html',
            controller: 'TrackDefController'
        }).
        when('/admin/trackDef/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/trackDef/trackDef-save.tpl.html',
            controller: 'TrackDefController'
        });
}])
```

How to highlight also pages with random address like:

> /admin/trackDef/123
>       /admin/trackDef/234
>       /admin/trackDef/534

etc

Comment: Can you post your route definition?

Comment: i have updated my question... its better now?

Comment: how do you trigger a route change?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22128830/949476) my answer on the similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify things a bit and just use the JS function `indexOf()`, similar to how you're using it in `isAnyActiveAdmin()`

Your `isActive()` would look similar to this:

```
$scope.isActive = function () {
    return $location.path().indexOf("admin") ? true : false
};
```

This would then work for any path that includes admin.