# How to define service variable as current route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, service, routes

I have some code...

```
spa.service("testService", function($route, $location, $routeParams) {

    this.testValue = $location.path();

})
```

This is pretty straightforward. I want the path after the `http://www.whatever.com`. The problem with this is that I want that value dynamically. I want it when I enter the page, and I want it when I change routes, etc.

I've tried using `$routes.current` I've tried using `$location.current,path()` and nothing works. I have to be missing something. I've read the documentation over and over, and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

The overall goal is to give some links on my page a certain class when their associated route is active. I'm attempting to do this by creating a function in the controller assigned to the links that returns a boolean based on whether or not the route variable I'm trying to declare is equal to the input of the aforementioned function. When the function outputs true,I use the `ng-class` directive to append the class to the correct link.

How do I assign `testValue` to the dynamic value of the route?

Comment: This seems to like your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15355346/2208096

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [@acicali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2208096/acicali)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130230/how-to-define-service-variable-as-current-route#comment50272305_31130230), you can do something like:

```
app.service('spasvc', function($rootScope, $location){
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e) {
    console.log('Route Change:', $location.path());
  });
});
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ov5lxGdEBPcwNeq9lfxT?p=preview

However, this only makes sense if you have a plan of mutating the service's internal state. And you can assign some variable to store value of `$location.path()`. It doesn't have much utility wherever injected. Of course, you can code around that, but there are better mechanisms to deal with that...

Comment: A couple questions. In the answer linked by @acicali the second function had a dependency on "e". What is that and why do I need it? Second, this works, but how are you accessing $routeChangeSuccess without adding it as a service dependency? Third, if I were to save the result of this function in a variable, would I do so by using the standard this.foobar = $location.path() or would I not be in the same scope because we're inside a $rootScope function?

Comment: I'll defer the answer to those questions to the angular chatroom... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63378/angularjs