# How to get the path name of the current route in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the path name of the current route as I define it in `$routeProvider`, i.e. `/customer/:id`.

`$location.path()` returns the path, `/customer/1`, but not the path name, `/customer/:id`.

I have found `$route.current.$$route.originalPath` that returns exactly what I need. However, I would like very much to not have to rely on private methods.

Is there a public equivalent of `$route.current.$$route.originalPath`?

Comment: May i know what exactly you wanted to do here

Comment: @PankajParkar May I know which part of the question is unclear to you?

Comment: After getting $$route.originalPath what you are doing with it?

Comment: That's irrelevant to the question. The question is all about if there's a public equivalent of `$route.current.$$route.originalPath`.

Comment: My question is simple, why do you need it in first place..? & How come imy question become irrelevant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the route name when location changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354329/how-to-get-the-route-name-when-location-changes)

Comment: @Pureferret, no, this is definitely not a duplicate of  that question. Please read this one carefully, especially the last question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you found another way to do this, and happened to come across this question while I was debugging some routing issues -

AFAIK the only way to get exactly what you need is to use:

```
$route.current.$$route.originalPath
```

Another way to handle this is using the broadcasted events like routeChangeStart/routeChangeSuccess to officially know which route was resolved.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, next, prev) {
    console.log(next.$$route.originalPath);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$route.current.originalPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$state.$current.url.sourcePath
```

But it is a little bit hacky too :)

Comment: Why do you say it's hacky?

Comment: Don't know, maybe it's because i've never used unresolved state url directly in state, so for me using of '$current' is a strange by the fact at all:) Note that you can also access unresolved state url in $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess listeners on $rootScope in second parameter (toState)

Comment: Sadly this is for `ui-router`. I was looking for a solution for `ngRoute`.